# strange link code in jquery -- adding target attributes

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, parent, target, rotator

Hours have already been spent because of my own programmer pride. The coding is calling information for the links from earlier input in the html. The first if then statement below is for the links on the "more" buttons in a rotator. The second is for the links on the corresponding thumbnails. After searching this site and finding similar posts, I found that none of them addressed targets for this type of link input. I just need a _parent target on them, that's all. Is there someway to incorporate "attr" to get a target _parent for the links in this type of code? Any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
if(! encDisableTextsAll && encEnableFooter)
{
    for(i=0; i<encNumOfImages; i++)
    {
        $(".footerTitle:eq(" + i + ")").html(encBannerTexts[i][0]);
        if(encEnableDescription) $(".footerDesc:eq(" + i + ")").html(encBannerTexts[i][1]);
        if(encBannerTexts[i][2] != "" & encEnableReadMore)
        {
            $(".footerLink:eq(" + i + ")").html("<div class='bttnMore'><a href='" + encBannerTexts[i][2] + "'>&nbsp;</a></div>");
        }
    } 
}
if(encEnableThumbImageLink && encEnableFooter)
{
    for(i=0; i<encNumOfImages; i++)
    {
        link = encBannerTexts[i][2];
        $("#thumbDiv_" + i).attr("onclick", "window.location.href='" + link + "'")

    }
}

// supposed link call
if ( (!elem[type] || (jQuery.nodeName(elem, 'a') && type == "click")) && elem["on"+type] &&      elem ["on"+type].apply( elem, data ) === false )
        event.result = false;
```

Comment: `top.window.location.href` would this work?

Comment: That worked for the thumbnail code... that is just divine. Any ideas on the first if...then code? Already, though, thank you so much.

Comment: just add `target="_parent"` to the link template you are using?

Comment: Like @AleksiYrttiaho pointed out, `$(".footerLink...<a target="_parent" ...>&nbsp;</a></div>");` should work.

Comment: Unrequested criticism: Instead of `$(...).attr('onclick',...);` you could use `$(...).click(function() { ... };`. That way you don't have to have javascript both as a string and as code. Also, please use the keyword `var` when you first introduce a variable: `for(var i=...)` instead of `for(i=...)`. It makes making hard to find bugs that much more arduous. You also seem to use a `&` instead of `&&`.  There's some other trivial changes that pop in my mind but I'll let them pass :)

Comment: By the way @Joseph, be sure to answer the question so that Ryan can accept it and save himself from a world of whining :)

Comment: Joseph: that was the first thing I tried. I actually get a syntax error with that.
Aleksi: hey I understand I do. My background is just not in jquery. I think I found the link template your referring to in the js file itself.

I'll post it above so the coding will show properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".footerLink:eq(" + i + ")").html("<div class='bttnMore'><a href='" + encBannerTexts[i][2] + "'>&nbsp;</a></div>");
```

should be

```
$(".footerLink:eq(" + i + ")").html("<div class='bttnMore'><a target=\"_parent\" href='" + encBannerTexts[i][2] + "'>&nbsp;</a></div>");
```

and

```
window.location.href
```

should be

```
top.window.location.href
```

Comment: The programming gods have spoken. Humankind can now continue progressing. Thank you both tons.